# Can I upload a file from a local directory to a program running on openshift?

Tags: spring-boot, openshift

I have a spring boot angular program that uploads a file from local directory. But when I run the program on openshift environment I cannot access that local directory anymore. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a file to pod using [`oc cp`](https://www.mankier.com/1/oc-cp) command

For example, if you want to upload a file 'file.tar.gz' to /tmp folder in pod 'test', you can run `oc cp file.tar.gz test:/tmp`.